# Rails 3, cucumber "unknown attribute"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

Starting out a tiny app with my first time using Cucumber 1.1.4 and it's erroring out with an "unknown attribute" error, it appears. I'd like to ensure a record exists, or created if not. I've made sure the show page exists with the erb calls and the record exists, just to be sure.

Here's my feature:

> Scenario: normal
>       Given an opening exists called "jobid", objective: "Work here", grizzard: "My experience", skills: "My skills"
>       When I go to the path "/openings/jobname"
>       Then I should see "Sam Walton"
>       Then I should see "Work here"
>       Then I should see "My experience"
>       Then I should see "My skills"

Here's my step file:

```
Given /^an opening exists called "([^"]*)", objective: "([^"]*)", bob: "([^"]*)", skills: "([^"]*)"$/ do
    |opening_name, objective_text, bob_text, skills_text|

    Opening.create!(name: opening_name, objective: objective_text, skills: skills_text, grizzard: bob_text) 
end

When /^I go to the path "([^"]*)"$/ do |path|
    visit(path)
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |text|
    page.should have_content(text)
end
```

Here's my error:

> # features/visitor_can_view_an_opening.feature:6
>       Given an opening exists called "jobid", objective: "Work here", grizzard: "My experience", skills: "My skills" #
>   features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:5
>         unknown attribute: skills (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
>        ./features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:6:in `/^an opening exists called "([^"]*)", objective: "([^"]*)", bob: "([^"]*)", skills:
>   "([^"]*)"$/`
>        features/visitor_can_view_an_opening.feature:7:in `Given an opening exists called "jobid", objective: "Work here", bob: "My
>   experience", skills: "My skills"`

I've looked over the skills: and it looks like the others, so my inexperience is in the way and would appreciate someone pointing out what I'm not understanding, sam

Comment: are you sure you have a skills column in your openings table?

Comment: Yes, I've even double checked the spelling in my development database. thx for checking.

Comment: Yes, but you have to have this column in test db as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, you may need to update your test environment database. Run

```
 rake db:test:prepare
```

It should work.

HTH.